# How can I calculate the determinant of a 40$\times$40 symbolic matrix?

Tags: matrix

I tried to find the characteristic equation of the 40$\times$40 symbolic function by calculating its determinant in Mathematica.
But Mathematica does not return me any output after long time calculating.
I don't know how can I get my answer from it.

```
a = ( {
   {-κ1/2 - λ, Δ1, -p1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {-Δ1, -κ1/2 - λ, Q1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, -λ, Ωm, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0},
   {Q1*G1, P1*G1, -Ωm, -γm - λ, Qw*Gw, 
    Pw*Gw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, -Pw*Gw, 0, -κw/2 - λ, Δw, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0},
   {0, 0, Qw*Gw, 0, -Δw, -κw/2 - λ, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -κp/2 - λ, Δp, 0, 
    J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -Δp, -κp/2 - λ, -J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    J1, -κ1/2 - λ, Δ1, -P1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/
    Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 
    0, -Δ1, -κ1/2 - λ, Q1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, -ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2],
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2]},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -λ, Ωm, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Q1*G1, 
    P1*G1, -Ωm, -γm - λ, Qw*Gw, Pw*Gw, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, -ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -pw*Gw, 
    0, -κw/2 - λ, Δw, 0, Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -ω, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Qw*Gw, 
    0, -Δw, -κw/2 - λ, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, -ω, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/Sqrt[
    2], -κp/2 - λ, Δp, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/
    Sqrt[2], 0, -ω, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/
    Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {-J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 
    0, -Δp, -κp/2 - λ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/
    Sqrt[2], 0, -ω, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[
    2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 0, ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -κ1/2 - λ, Δ1, -p1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[
    2]},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1, 0, ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -Δ1, -κ1/2 - λ, Q1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[
    2], 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -λ, Ωm, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, Q1*G1, 
    P1*G1, -Ωm, -γm - λ, Qw*Gw, Pw*Gw, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ω, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 
    0, 0, -Pw*Gw, 0, -κw/2 - λ, Δw, 
    0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ω, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[2], 
    0, 0, Qw*Gw, 0, -Δw, -κw/2 - λ, Jw/
    Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, ω, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw/Sqrt[
    2], -κp/2 - λ, Δp, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, J1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/Sqrt[2], 0, ω, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, Jw/Sqrt[2], 
    0, -Δp, -κp/2 - λ, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 
    0, -κ1/2 - λ, Δ1, -p1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, -2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[
    2], -Δ1, -κ1/2 - λ, Q1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -λ, Ωm, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, Q1*G1, P1*G1, -Ωm, -γm - λ, 
    Qw*Gw, Pw*Gw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, -Pw*Gw, 
    0, -κw/2 - λ, Δw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2*ω, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Qw*Gw, 
    0, -Δw, -κw/2 - λ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2*ω, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -(J1/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -κp/2 - λ, Δp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2*ω, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -(J1/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -Δp, -κp/2 - λ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -2*ω},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -κ1/2 - λ, Δ1, -p1*G10, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, -J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -Δ1, -κ1/2 - λ, Q1*G1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -λ, Ωm, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, Q1*G1, 
    P1*G1, -Ωm, -γm - λ, Qw*Gw, Pw*Gw, 0,
     0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Pw*Gw, 
    0, -κw/2 - λ, Δw, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Jw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 0, Qw*Gw, 
    0, -Δw, -κw/2 - λ, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, J1/
    Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -κp/2 - λ, Δp},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Jw, 0, 0, 0, J1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -J1/
    Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2*ω, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -Δp, -κp/2 - λ}
  } )

aa=Det[a]
```

Comment: Maybe you could write it as a smaller block matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices . Where did the 40x40 matrix come from and is it generated from other code or a solution to something else that is short enough to paste here ?

Comment: these matrix is a drift matrix of quantum system with eight degree of freedom with time dependence. I want to drive Routh-Hurwitz criteria condition for stability of these sysytem. I can mail it for you because i can not summarize or block diagonal it.

Comment: Perhaps you could `Compress[m]` it and paste the resulting string in the question or a pastebin instead?

Comment: finally by adding notes i can paste the matrix

Comment: Without any way to reduce it into simpler blocks, this matrix is too big and too complex to get a symbolic determinant in a reasonable time frame. The result will also be far too big and unwieldy to use anyway, even though it's a fairly sparse matrix.

Comment: So the matrix (without the lambdas) is a Jacobian matrix for some system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

Below link gives general determinat formula.
http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/determ1/determ1.html

You can use below stages:

- Find symbolic determint in terms of cofactors (Aij submatrices).
- Find cofactors in terms of smaller cofactors.
- Make some trials to figure out right submatrix size.
- Derive the symbolic expression.

You can use below code to make some trials:

```
detA = 0;
n = 2;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
    detA = detA +
       Symbol["a" <> If[i < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[i] <> If[j < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[j]]*
        Symbol["A" <> If[i < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[i] <> If[j < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[j]];
    ];
  ];
Print["For n=", n, " detA: ", detA];
```

EDIT 1:
The code above is not correct. The code has been corrected and improved. Errors stated in the comment section.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{i, j, ij, detA = 0},
  For[ij = 1, ij <= n, ij++,
   Switch[d,
    "Row", i = x; j = ij;,
    "Column", j = x; i = ij;];
   detA = detA + (-1)^(i + j)*
      Symbol["a" <> If[i < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[i] <> 
        If[j < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[j]]*
      Symbol["A" <> If[i < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[i] <> 
        If[j < 10, "0", ""] <> ToString[j]];
   ];
  detA],
 {{n, 1, "Matrix Size"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{d, "Row", "Which dimension will be fixed"}, {"Row", "Column"}},
 {{x, 1, "Fixed row/column number"}, 1, n, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {n, d, x}]
```

Comment: by these code you mean I calculate the determinant by putting any elements of matrix in determinant formula?

Comment: @nafisgh. I have found two problem in my code. Firstly I have forgetten (-1)^(i+j) term. Secondly either row number or column number should be fixed in the formula. I have corrected my code and improved it. –

Comment: Does this compute the determinant of the matrix in the original post?

Comment: Not so easy. Formula should be used as nested.